# Using AlertDialog on a stack widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a basic layout where I am using a stack widget to hold my other widgets.. I have a side toolbar, inside that I have a pen menu on click of which a popup should appear. When i am clicking the pen menu an  [alert dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCf2H.png) appears but not in the expected place, what i mean is...

I am expecting a dialog like the one in the below image. Do I need to use any plugin to create a dialog like this with a chevron mark?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNSgR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Alert dialog, it will by default be aligned in center of your screen. In order to achieve what you are trying to, I would suggest using a plugin like [this](https://github.com/chinabrant/popup_menu).